# How to generate ReportExecutionService from sql reporting services server

Tags: java, soap, reporting-services, wsdl

I'm trying to render SSRS reports from a java web application.  It appears that I will need to use the SOAP API for SQL reporting services.  So far, I have followed the instructions in this blog post: https://surendragurjar.wordpress.com/2015/07/11/ssrs-wsdl-web-service-endpoint-using-java/

I am running a 2014 SQL reporting services server and using Java 1.8.

wsimport generates lots of java classes in the correct package but does NOT generate ReportExecutionService.  I don't know how to proceed without this class.

What settings need to be enabled on the server and what changes should I make to my wsimport process in order to generate all the necessary class files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is just a minor issue with the blog post I was following.  The intended soap schema address for report rendering is `reportexecution2005`, not `reportservice2005`.  After switching to the correct URI, everything else in that blog post works!